# Solve $x + \frac{ 1 }{y+1/3}=38/3$ in the set of natural numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

The following equation should have a solution with $x,y$ being natural numbers. I cannot find it. Is there such solution?

$$x + \frac{ 1 }{y+1/3}=\frac{38}{3}$$

Comment: There are no solutions.

Comment: You can see that there is no solution since the reduced denominator of the result is a divisor of $3y+1$, and $3$ is never a divisor of $3y+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing the expression as:

$$x+\frac{3}{3y+1}$$ we see that the denominator of the result has to be $3y+1$, and you can't get $3y+1=3$. No solution.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

$$x+\frac{1}{y+1/3}=38/3$$
$$3x+\frac{9}{3y+1}=38$$
$$3x(3y+1)+9=38(3y+1)$$
$$(3x-38)(3y+1)=-9$$
$$(38-3x)(3y+1)=9$$

Comment: I remember yet that $ 9  = 3 \times 3$ and $-9 = -3\times 3.$

Comment: And since the left is $\equiv2\pmod3$ while the right is $\equiv0\pmod3$, you get . . .